# Porting addons to Mozilla Prism 1.0b1

Tags: mozilla, mozilla-prism

I'm trying to port an application to the newest version of Mozilla Prism (1.0b1 currently).  The instructions say to put this in install.rdf:

```
<em:targetApplication>
    <!-- Prism -->
    <Description>
        <em:id>prism@developer.mozilla.org</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>0.4</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>1.0.0.*</em:maxVersion>
    </Description>
</em:targetApplication>
```

However, for maxVersion, I can't find an entry which allows it to install.  I've tried 1.1b1.*, 1.1, 1.*, nothing.

Anybody understand how to do this?

TIA
Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Prism/Extensions

Are you sure the MaxVersion is the problem?

```
<em:maxVersion>1.0.0.*</em:maxVersion>
```

is in the example.

Also,
http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/planet-mozilla/extending-prism/ and
http://code.google.com/p/hunspell-spellcheck-vi/source/browse/trunk/firefox_thunderbird/install.rdf?r=53 use that MaxVersion

Comment: Excellent, this was just what I needed.  The rdf format had changed, and your first link pointed to that.